# momentjs date difference return wrong

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I using `countdown.js` and want to add `60 days` to a `date` (data taken from DB). I did this in `targetDay`  and it's working fine, now I want to calculate this date from now but it return an odd date `"1969-11-05T21:24:07.416Z"` why?

```js
const nowDate = moment();
const targetDay = moment('2020-10-24 14:25:26').add('60', 'days');
const countdown = moment(nowDate - targetDay);


console.log(countdown);
//const diff = targetDay.fromNow();

const count_days = countdown.format('D');
const count_hours = countdown.format('HH');
const count_minutes = countdown.format('mm');
const count_seconds = countdown.format('ss');
console.log(count_days + ' days:' + count_hours + ' hrs:' + count_minutes + ' m:' + count_seconds + ' s');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

I tried `fromNow()` function but it return in `string`. What I trying to do is, making a countdown to target day from now.

Comment: `nowDate - targetDay` amounts to `-4855971015`. Passing that to moment goes back ~56 days from Jan 1st, 1970

Comment: `moment()` is for dates. `moment.duration()` is for duration. You'll need to adjust how you get and use `countdown`. `const countdown = moment.duration(nowDate.diff(targetDay));`

Comment: @Ouroborus did you tried this? not working for me!

Comment: You will, of course, need to make further adjustments since things like `.format()` aren't available to durations. Reading [the documentation](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/) may help.

Comment: All this is quite funny considering that my very first comment is precisely answering the question you asked: `it return an odd date "1969-11-05T21:24:07.416Z" why?` Anyway, I don't care about rep, and I'm not here to put down newbies. You are not a newbie in any sense anyway, your earliest JS question is from almost three years ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.duration()` then get your remaining time with `.hours()` and `.minutes()` and `.seconds()`, these functions convert from `milliseconds`

https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/

```js
setInterval(function() { // remove
  const nowDate = moment();
  const targetDay = moment('2030-10-24 14:25:26').add('60', 'days'); // I changed to 2030 to keep this snippet live for future ;)
  const countdown = moment.duration(targetDay.diff(nowDate));

  const count_days = Math.floor(countdown.asDays());
  const count_hours = countdown.hours();
  const count_minutes = countdown.minutes();
  const count_seconds = countdown.seconds();
  $('div').text(count_days + ' days:' + count_hours + ' hrs:' + count_minutes + ' m:' + count_seconds + ' s');
}, 1000); // remove
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

Just remove `setInterval` in your code, this just for *demo!*

---

*I changed to 2030 to keep this snippet live for future ;)*

Answer (score 1):

Use [`moment.diff()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/) instead of the direction mathematical subtraction.

This will create a `moment.duration` (by default in miliseconds).

```js
const nowDate = moment();
const targetDay = moment('2020-10-24 14:25:26').add('60', 'days');
const countdownDiff = targetDay.diff(nowDate)
// 4855463420
```

Your constants for differnece should also be measured in duration, because a **format of the added difference is not the duration**.

> eg. 28 October + 60 days => 28 December. But `moment('28-12-2020').format('D')` is `28` isntead of the `60` you want to display.

So you'll need to store them individually as a difference as well

```js
const count_days = targetDay.diff(nowDate, 'd');
const count_hours = targetDay.diff(nowDate, 'h');
const count_minutes = targetDay.diff(nowDate, 'm');
const count_seconds = targetDay.diff(nowDate, 's');
```

And if you wish to convert it back to a moment, you can add the difference to the original one. This only serves as an illustration as to how the diff is calcualted

```js
const countdown = nowDate.add(countdownDiff, 'ms')
// obviously this is redundant as it's the same as targetDay
```

Here's a working example:

```js
const nowDate = moment();
const targetDay = moment('2020-10-24 14:25:26').add('60', 'days');
const countdownDiff = targetDay.diff(nowDate)
// 4855463420


const countdown = moment(nowDate).add(countdownDiff, 'ms')
// obviously this is redundant as it's the same as targetDay

const count_days = targetDay.diff(nowDate, 'days');
const count_hours = targetDay.diff(nowDate, 'h');
const count_minutes = targetDay.diff(nowDate, 'm');
const count_seconds = targetDay.diff(nowDate, 's');

console.log('Current day:', nowDate.format('Do MMM YYYY HH:mm'));
console.log('Target day:', targetDay.format('Do MMM YYYY HH:mm'));
console.log('Countdown end date', countdown.format('Do MMM YYYY HH:mm'));

console.log(count_days + ' days:' + count_hours + ' hrs:' + count_minutes + ' m:' + count_seconds + ' s');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @ChrisG I'm bit on the fence on the question / answer. While I do despise help vampires myself, it's hard for me to tell whether OP genuinely just doesn't understand the difference between duration and date or is really just seeking for someone to do the work for them. Personally I wouldn't mind deleting it for the behaviour displayed in comments but at the same time I feel like the answer could actually be useful for the rest of the userbase who view the answer also days later after they actually visit the question. Perhaps it would be worth opening case @ meta about the user in particular?

Comment: I've removed my comments; I agree that this answer might be useful to somebody else. And in my opinion it's not worth the effort to pursue this any further. In my experience it's better to stick to downvotes and close votes.